# Update three.js material without hiding the object

Tags: three.js, textures

Is there a way I can update a three.js material without hiding the object it is applied to.

The only thing I came up with was to clone the object and the material, update the cloned material using `material.needsUpdate = true` and replacing the original object with the cloned one.

Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: you shouldn't have to `clone()` the object before applying `material.needsUpdate = true` to it.

Comment: I know but when I don't clone it my object will be hidden for a short time. This is very bad in my situation as I update the material a few times per second.

Comment: How exactly are you updating the material?

Comment: I generate and set a new `alphaMap`

Comment: Try to generate and load to buffer THREE.ImageUtils texture first and after finishing replace to material.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but could you explain your hint a little more please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it was a stupid mistake on my side. I changed my code to use `THREE.TextureLoader()` and preload the texture. Now everything is working fine.